# getting outofmemory error in grails run-app

Tags: grails, out-of-memory

I am trying to execute grails run-app and getting out of memory error. 
  [groovyc] java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

I have set grails_opts as: GRAILS_OPTS="-XX:MaxPermSize=2048m -Xmx4096M -server"

Tried various options for JAVA_OPTS also but still getting outofmemory error.

Comment: What is the RAM/Memory of your machine?

Comment: memory of my machine is 16gb

Comment: I think you should look at your code. Are you using any plugins? It seems you have a memory leak of some kind in your application.

Comment: Is there a way to figure out what is causing the memory leak? I know there are diagnostic tools but other team members have the same code base and it works for them totally fine.

Comment: This has happened to me twice when I was using an older/newer version of java and it had a known issue(Early days of java 7), the second time was caused by a plugin which was fixed by deleting the .grails folder of that project and cleaning the project. Maybe you could try doing those things although I suspect you already have.  You could use the profiler that is included in the netbeans release to examine the memory usage of your application.

Comment: You say that you've set your heap size using GRAILS_OPTS, but are you absolutely certain that the Grails process you're running has picked up that setting?